# Format a Freshdesk Solution On My Own Site

Tags: html, api, freshdesk, freshworks

I'm building a website where I want to display my Freshdesk solution articles to my users with custom css styling. My API calls are successfully returning the solution articles, but the description_text property which holds the content of the articles is just a string of text (there is no html). How can I get this data formatted as an html string from the Freshdesk API? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Err... something like this?

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <p style={/* whatever crazy style */}>
      {description_text}
    </p>
  )
};
```

*Man it is so hard to answer when people make vague questions...*

Comment: *Man that is why we don't bother answering vauge questions and use the tools at our disposal to prompt OPs to improve their questions*

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer. You need to query the API for `description`, not `description_text`. This will return formatted html and not just plain text. Really simple!